# Algorithm to query between which boundaries a number is in

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to query what interval in a set of non-overlapping intervals a number is in.
I realise that there are numerous solutions to this problem out there already, but I believe that my case is yet again special and somewhat different.

I am dynamically adding and removing boundaries that segregate the interval from negative to positive infinity into sections. There are no holes in these sections, i.e. the set of boundaries/intervals is continuous. This means that when a boundary is removed, the sections below and above it are merged.

The boundaries are added in no particular order. See the following image for clarification:

[image]

In case the queried number is exactly on a boundary, I don't care which of the regions it belongs to, and want to return either one of them.

The number of queries may be considerably larger or considerably smaller than the number of boundaries.

A naive algorithm would run in O(n). Assuming that until the next query is made, the set of boundaries will have changed completely, this could be faster than using binary search trees, I think (?), but this does not seem like an optimal solution.

Is there some algorithm that fits this scenario?

Comment: You could use a self-balancing binary search tree, e.g. a Red-Black tree, which can handle efficient inserts / deletions and (just about) guarantee O(log n) search time

Comment: However, in some cases the naive approach would be faster. Consider adding n segments in O(n log n) time, making one query in O(log n), and then deleting the segments in O(n log n) time, versus O(n) for the naive approach. While in many cases a RB tree will be better, it seems weird that a naive approach can sometimes beat it, which leads me to believe that there must be a better option.

Comment: For the specific case where you add / delete all elements in one go, you can just insert them all into an ordinary binary tree and perform balancing on the entire tree in O(n) (see this page: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-normal-bst-balanced-bst/). Also you can free all nodes together at O(n).

Comment: I ended up implementing a red-black tree, which seems to do the job quite well. To anyone with the same problem in the future: Know what you're getting into before you start implementing red-black trees.

Comment: There are many external libraries (and even code samples) of RB tree implementations. (I believe even STL has one - for `<map>`; however it might be internal)

Comment: Yes, but overriding `map` to a) use floats as keys and b) find in between which keys a point lies introduces quite some overhead. As for code samples, most are of the form "can you tell me what's wrong" or of the form "your code does not compile ..." (which, to be frank, was not surprising seeing some of the junk out there).

Comment: I don't mean that you should override `<map>`; I was simply pointing out that there are *so many* tested implementations of RB trees out there (many of them templated), there is no need for you to reinvent the wheel. Example sources include Github and various university websites, as well as coding blogs (not stackoverflow because it is, as you said, full of noobs). But this is going off-topic - as long as you have it working, everything is good.